# Issues with Splitting GeoJSON Path

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am working on a React application using React-Leaflet for mapping functionalities. I'm facing an issue with dynamically splitting a GeoJSON LineString path based on a slider value and then rendering this splitted path.

My GeoJSON data consists of multiple LineString features. I'm trying to split these LineStrings dynamically when a slider value changes. The slider represents a time scale (minutes), and the idea is to display only the portion of the path that corresponds to the slider's current value.

When I place a marker on the map, it automatically finds the nearest point on a GeoJSON path, which becomes the start of the path segment I want to display. The slider I use then determines the end of this segment. Essentially, the marker sets the starting point by finding the closest path point, and the slider lets me adjust where this segment ends, allowing me to dynamically visualize specific portions of the path.

The issue with my application always rendering the same split path segment, regardless of the marker or slider position, likely stems from the fact that it's only considering the first feature of the GeoJSON data. This means that each time I try to split and display a path segment based on the marker's location and the slider's value, the code is repeatedly using the first set of coordinates from the first feature in the GeoJSON file, ignoring subsequent features and their coordinates. As a result, the same path segment is displayed every time, without responding to changes in the marker or slider positions.

I'd like to mention that the code snippet I'm sharing is part of a larger experimentation process. I'm aware that it might seem unconventional or 'messy' as I've been trying out various approaches to solve this issue, including some trial-and-error methods. The main objective here is to pinpoint the root cause of the problem, and any refinement of the code will be part of future iterations. I appreciate your understanding and am looking forward to your insights and suggestions!

```
    function getMarkerIndex(markerPosition, sliderValue) {
        console.log('sliderValue:', sliderValue); 

        const sliderValueNumber = sliderValue[0];
        console.log('sliderValueNumber:', sliderValueNumber);

        const flattenedCoordinates = IsarDaten2.features.flatMap(feature => feature.geometry.coordinates);
        console.log('flattenedCoordinates:', flattenedCoordinates);

        const totalCoordinates = flattenedCoordinates.reduce((total, coords) => total + coords.length, 0);
        console.log('totalCoordinates:', totalCoordinates);

        let startIndex = flattenedCoordinates.findIndex(coords => coords[0] === markerPosition[0] && coords[1] === markerPosition[1]);
        console.log('startIndex:', startIndex);

        let endIndex = Math.round(sliderValueNumber * (totalCoordinates - 1));
        console.log('endIndex:', endIndex);

        if (startIndex > endIndex) {
            [startIndex, endIndex] = [endIndex, startIndex];
        }

        let splitPart = flattenedCoordinates.slice(startIndex, endIndex);

        const data = splitPart.map(([lng, lat], index, array) => {
            const value = index / (array.length - 1);
            return { lat, lng, value };
        });
        console.log('data:', data);

        setSplitLine(data);
    }
```

[image: Gradient Position has nothing to do with the marker position]

I've already attempted over 10 different solutions to address the issue in my application, including automatically reformatting the GeoJSON, manually adjusting its format, and even converting the data into a MultiLineString, but these efforts have not resolved the problem.